# Problem with static variable from class that extends an abstract

Tags: php, static, php-7.2

Why is this code outputting "third third third"?

```php
<?php

abstract class xyz {

    static $var;

    public static function setVar($value) {
        static::$var = $value;
    }
}

class one extends xyz {}

class two extends xyz {}
class three extends xyz {}

call_user_func('one::setVar', 'first');
call_user_func('two::setVar', 'second');
call_user_func('three::setVar', 'third');

echo "<pre>";
echo one::$var."\n";
echo two::$var."\n";
echo three::$var."\n";
echo "</pre>";
```

I would have thought first, second third

What am I missing here?

### Update

This was my resolution

```
public static function setVar($value) {
        $class = get_called_class();
        $class::$var =& $value;
    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577187/php-5-3-late-static-binding-doesnt-work-for-properties-when-defined-in-parent

Comment: Thanks @Clive  I didn't know what I was looking for.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/GKmUr